# How to use sequence from scalaz to transform T[G[A]] to G[T[A]]

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

I have this code to transform List[Future[Int]] to Future[List[Int]] by using scalaz sequence.

```
import scalaz.concurrent.Future

val t = List(Future.now(1), Future.now(2), Future.now(3)) //List[Future[Int]]
val r = t.sequence //Future[List[Int]]
```

because I am using Future from scalaz, so it may have implicit resolution to do the magic for me, I just wonder if the type class is custom class not predefined one like Future, how can I define implicit resolution to achieve the same result

```
case class Foo(x: Int)

val t = List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)) //List[Foo[Int]]

val r = t.sequence //Foo[List[Int]]
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an `Applicative[Foo]` (or a `Monad[Foo]`) which is in implicit scope.

What you are asking for exactly won't work, since your `Foo` is not universally quantified (so your expected type for `r` doesn't make sense as `Foo[List[Int]]`, since `Foo` doesn't take a type parameter.

Lets define `Foo` differently:

```
case class Foo[A](a: A)

object Foo {
  implicit val fooApplicative = new Applicative[Foo] {
      override def point[A](a: => A) = Foo(a)
      override def ap[A,B](fa: => Foo[A])(f: => Foo[A=>B]): Foo[B] = Foo(f.a(fa.a))
  } 
}
```

Now if we make sure this implicit is in scope, we can sequence:

```
scala> val t = List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)) 
t: List[Foo[Int]] = List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3))

scala> t.sequence
res0: Foo[List[Int]] = Foo(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, one typo is override def point(a: => A) = Foo(a) should be changed to override def point[A](a: => A) = Foo(a).